# QGIS relation reference widget shows an empty list instead of values

Tags: qgis, widget, relation

I'm trying to set up a QField project to entry data from a bird watch project.
I have a few layers which I would like to connect with the ID of the tour.
I am using relation reference widgets.
The problem is, that if I want to select a tour ID in the layers, the list is empty.

How can I change it so it will show the ID of the tour I need?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The display expression is the one of the target (parent) layer. In your case "Adulte". In case there is no field called "Rundgang ID", then the display text is empty.